# Error: Installing vagrant gem in ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, ruby-2.0

When I tried to install **vagrant** gem in **ruby 2.0.0-p0**, I am getting follwoing error:

```
~ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
~ gem -v
2.0.0.rc.2
~ gem list json
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
json (1.7.7)

~ gem install vagrant
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing vagrant:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/re.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile
make
compiling generator.c
generator.c: In function ‘cState_aref’:
generator.c:736:5: warning: variable ‘state’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 generator.so /home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/json-1.5.5/ext/json/ext/json/ext
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/json-1.5.5/ext/json/ext/json/ext': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1
Gem files will remain installed in /home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/json-1.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/json-1.5.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I figure, its using **json-1.5.5** from /home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/ while building the gem and getting the above error.

I tried re-installing the latest **json-1.7.7** gem and still it fails to install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your rubygems with: `gem update --system`

Here is the commit that fixed this issue: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/1ca11d00833bbca33215ff581303d1fee8f2d1ef

Comment: Thanks, I had recently installed ruby-2.0.0 and had assumed that its using the latest rubygem. With this update, vagrant is successfully installed along with it's dependencies including json 1.5.5.

Comment: I'm using ruby-2.0.0-p0 (installed with RVM), MonngoDB 2.3.3 and gem 2.0.0.rc.2 but it's not working...